# PhoneGap Ripple Emulator always reports malformed config.xml

Tags: cordova, ripple, phonegap-build

Does anyone have any idea, what can cause Ripple Emulator (newesest version) onboard newest version of Chrome to **always** report malformed or missing config file ("*config.xml file could not be found in application's root or is malformed XML*")?

I have my `config.xml` present exactly at application root (i.e. in the same folder, where `index.html` file, used to fire my mobile application). I don't think it's malformed since `PhoneGap Bulid` builds perfectly working applications (though tested only on Android) and does not reports any problems neither with configuration file nor with compilation process.

I'm getting this error not only on my own configuration files, but also on any PhoneGap application, that I've been working with -- including: PhoneGap Hello World example application, alluny's PhoneGap Start Application, Sencha Touch Kitchen Sink demo and others. Actually I haven't found any application in my local resources, that would not cause Ripple Emulator to report problems with `config.xml` file.

Of course, I set proper Chrome's settings, as instructed on Ripple Emulator page and I'm opening my Chrome with proper flag to allow it access local files via *file:///* protocol.

Comment: Same here, both with yeoman's internal server and with Xampp. If config.xml is clearly requested and served from the project root according to the Network tab of developer tools - nevertheless Ripple complains about it not being found.

Comment: Are you loading your app in Ripple through a web server (e.g. http://localhost/foo/index.html), or from the file system (file:///C:/Users/foo/index.html)?

Comment: @AdamStanley: Both ways and both fails. I've opened a ticket in Ripple support, as Ripple authors said, this shouldn't happen and that his have to be some sort of bug. Nothing changed (checked seconds ago) ever since that. Ripple updated itself few times, ticket remains open and I don't see any changes in this area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am using the current Ripple UI (v0.9.15) and experienced this issue too.

For me the issue was caused by not having the config file in the right location. After I put it in the correct location, Ripple did not recognize it until I disabled/re-enabled Ripple.

What worked for me was:

1. Make sure config.xml is in the www root with index.html (where you currently have it)
2. Click on the green Ripple icon in the top left and disable Ripple for that page
3. Re-enable Ripple

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer, though I don't use this solution (Ripple Emulator) at all. It turned out, that it stopped working for me. Even after re-install and with using `--allow-file-access-from-files` it does not respond for clicking `Enable` or `Disable`. Either I'm very unlucky or Ripple is to deep in beta, containing many strange bugs, so I dropped the entire idea in favor of testing apps directly on devices, using services like TestFlight and similar. Thanks.

Comment: One and a half month later I've come back to using Ripple Emulator, but this issue remains, both at mine side and in the form of unresolved bug on Ripple GitHub issues side. I don't know what have worked for you, but I can't reproduce this solution. My Ripple Emulator claims all the time that my `config.xml` file is missing or invalid.

Comment: This answer does not seem to work. I am using phonegap 2.9.0 as of Sept 2013. Ripple still shows lots of problems with config.xml.

Answer (score 4):

Just solved this problem, here's what I had to do:

1. Transfer the **config.xml** to my root path (same path as the index.html file)
2. Transfer the **/res** folder as well or edit all the .XML entries to point to the right paths.
3. Disable Ripple and then Re-Enable.

Comment: This causes the plugins tab to be lost in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 3):

It took me awhile to get the switch working, but opening Chrome with the --allow-file-access-from-files switch is the solution.

Comment: Using `--allow-file-access-from-files` is required to have Ripple working at all and it was first thing I did during my tests. It has nothing to do with working (or not) `config.xml` file. Some people using this switch reports that their Ripple reads configuration without problems, while others (like me) can't force Ripple to read `config.xml` no matter, if they use `--allow-file-access-from-files` switch or not.