# Ripple incorrectly renders mobile application elements

Tags: cordova, ripple

I've started my mobile application development journey and found fantastic Ripple Emulator. But I'm having a problem, that it does not render emulated application correctly.

For selected platform (Android + PhoneGap 2.3.0) and device (Galaxy Nexus phone) every application's elements are way much bigger, than it actually appears on device.

For example, images are much bigger (example 250x250 image fill nearly entire Ripple Emulator screen while on Nexus, it only takes small part of screen with its native resolution -- 720x1280). Texts with 14pt font size are also very big, while on Nexus they're are so small that nearly hard to read. And so on.

It also fails to respond to standard JavaScript events. For example, I see no effect, when I manually fire *deviceready* event, while on my Nexus I clearly see text alert message, I've put there.

This makes testing mobile apps under Ripple Emulator quite useless, at least for me.

I was wondering, if this could be caused by [Ripple being unable to read application's configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832776/phonegap-ripple-emulator-always-reports-malformed-config-xml). But can there be any connection between missing configuration and problems in CSS interpretation?

What can be wrong or what do I miss?  I've set proper Chrome's settings, as instructed on Ripple Emulator page and I'm opening my Chrome with proper flag to allow it access local files via *file:///* protocol. I'm quite out of ideas, what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set the zoom level of *Chrome* to 100%.

Comment: No, that is not a problem. I have always Chrome zoom set to 100%. Newest versions of Chrome includes warning icon on omnibox (omnibar) that warns user, whenever he or she has zoom different than 100%.